# jQuery selector not working properly. Possible Sizzle bug?

Tags: jquery, selector, sizzle

jQuery is what I live and breathe. Just recently (as of going to >= 1.10.1) jQuery is having "hiccups" with selectors. For example, selecting `$("#catalog")` will only return one element, whereas selecting `$("div#catalog")` returns two. Also, I have had issues in the recent past where a selector such as `$("#page_id > div.my_class .all_children")` returned nothing, but `$("#page_id").find("div.my_class").find(".all_children")` returned what I wanted it to (no working example currently).

I *do* have a reproducible example on jsFiddle that has the same "problem" on Firefox and Chrome (I haven't tested any other browser). I thought I would post this here first to get input before I post it as a bug on jQuery.com.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I misunderstand Sizzle and selectors? I know the "div#id" is generally faster than just "#id" (correct?), but shouldn't they both work anyway?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Selector (#catalog): " + $("#catalog").length + " / " +      $("#catalog").find(".field_grid").length);
    console.debug("Without div: ", $("#catalog"), $("#catalog").find(".field_grid"));
    alert("Selector (div#catalog): " + $("div#catalog").length + " / " + $("div#catalog").find(".field_grid").length);
    console.debug("With div: ", $("div#catalog"), $("div#catalog").find(".field_grid"));
});
```

The above code will return different results, even though the selectors are nearly identical.

Take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AVWgW/2/. Also, take a look at the console, I am dumping the return objects from jQuery.

Ideas?

Comment: Well, it is invalid to have multiple elements with the same ID. No telling what you'll get back when you do that. I wouldn't be surprised to see that produce totally unpredictable results in native javascript across all sorts of browsers.

Comment: IDs are meant to be unique in a document - you definitely want classes - doing a selector of #catalog correctly uses the native getElementById to retrieve the element, which will only ever return 1 element. If you do div#catalog, sizzle kicks in and you get what you "expect" but what is actually incorrect and should be fixed :)

Comment: Why would you expect an ID selector to give you multiple results? that would be invalid html, meaning it isn't Sizzle's or jquery's fault, it would be yours

Comment: Honestly, I am voting to close as off topic as the duplicate ID demonstrates a lack of minimal understanding of the HTML specification back to 4.0 outlined in 1999

Comment: Cool! Thanks, I thought it might be something I was doing. I was not aware that ID's had to be unique throughout the whole document. Learn something new everyday, right? Thanks to everyone!

Comment: @user2379136 - One of the first steps of debugging Javascript is to run your HTML through a validator.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss To be fair, since it is hard to get an error by doing this, it is _somewhat_ understandable how someone could be ignorant of this.

Comment: Also to address the rest of your question your second set of selectors are actually not equivalent. `$("#page_id > div.my_class .all_children")` is equivalent to `$("#page_id").children("div.my_class").find(".all_children")` not `$("#page_id").find("div.my_class").find(".all_children")`

Comment: Also `div#id` is actually slower than `#id` as targeting solely by id is handled by the native `getElementById()` method.

Comment: @user2532739 normally true, but that first sentence in the question text and the entire context of the question is about multiple id's so  that makes it a close vote however brutal that might be construed.

Answer (score 2):

You are repeating the use of an ID `catalog`.

This is not allowed in HTML, `ID`s must be unique.

So, when you enter the territory of undefined behavior, anything can happen.